# PySpark dataframe Pandas UDF returns empty dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to apply a `pandas_udf` to my PySpark dataframe for some filtering, following the `groupby('Key').apply(UDF)` method. To use the `pandas_udf` I defined an output `schema` and have a condition on the column `Number`. As an example, the simplified idea here is that I wish only to return the `ID` of the rows with odd `Number`.

This now brings up a problem that sometimes there is no odd `Number` in a group therefore the UDF just returns an empty dataframe, which is in conflict with the defined `schema` to return an `int` for `Number`.

Is there a way to solve this problem and only output and combine all the odd `Number` rows as a new dataframe?

```
schema = StructType([
        StructField("Key", StringType()),
        StructField("Number", IntegerType())
    ])
```

```
@pandas_udf(schema, functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
    def get_odd(df):
        odd = df.loc[df['Number']%2 == 1]
        return odd[['ID', 'Number']]
```

Comment: Because I wish to deploy the algorithm on a cluster and groupby enables distributed computing. Conducting the conditions i have on a huge dataframe is very expensive without groupby.

Comment: Use a if/else to return an empty data frame with columns defined ? Also how does your return match the schema as you have only the `ID` column returned ?

Comment: That's a typo, just fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

I come across this issue with null DataFrame in some groups. I solve this by checking for empty DataFrame and return a DataFrame with schema defined:

```
if df_out.empty:
    # change the schema as needed
    return pd.DataFrame({'fullVisitorId': pd.Series([], dtype='str'),
                         'time': pd.Series([], dtype='datetime64[ns]'),
                         'total_transactions': pd.Series([], dtype='int')})
```

Comment: I've found that it's sufficient to provide the column names alone. So if something goes wrong in my `pandas_udf` functions and I want to return an empty pandas dataframe I just do: `return pd.DataFrame(columns=schema.fieldNames())`, where `schema` is the schema of the Spark DataFrame (to be returned) which you passed into your `pandas_udf` function.